# File.Move() closes Console window automatically in C#

Tags: c#, file, filesystemwatcher

I have a simple **C# Console** application in which I use **FileSystemWatcher** and Moving files from one destiantion to another when they are created. My code looks like this:

```
    public static void WatchForFiles()
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        //folder path is path to folder
        watcher.Path = folderPath;

        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
            | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

        //Add event handlers           
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(File_OnChanged);        

        //Begin watching
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }


    public static void File_OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        //destiantion path is path to folder
        string destiantionFileFullPath = destianationPath + e.Name;
        if (!File.Exists(destiantionFileFullPath))
        {
            File.Move(e.FullPath, destiantionFileFullPath);
        }
    }
```

When I copy a file first time it is moved normally. But after that or if I copy two or more files my console windows is closed automatically. I think I should use **IAsyncResult** but I don't know how. I tried **Tasks** but that didn't help. Firs copying file and then deleting didn't help either. What causes to this and how can I prevent this? Thanks  in advance

Comment: Sounds like you have an exception thrown somewhere. Create a bat file where you call your window console program and then pause.

Comment: From memory I believe it is possible that the FileWatcher will notify you of a new file before the file has been completely written to disk (so you may be attempting to move a file that is still locked for writing). Put a try{} catch block around the File.Move and WriteLine the exception to the console - that might help you get to the bottom of the problem.

Comment: When I use try catch everything works and no exception is thrown it is so strange

Comment: Put `Console.ReadLine();` at the end of Main() and try again.

Comment: @AdilMammadov - have you put a Console.WriteLine(...) in the catch block so you can see what the exception is?

Comment: @HansPassant I have already put ConsoleReadline()

Comment: @KazR Yes, I have written. But nothing is displayed. I also put breakpoint into cath block but it has never been reached.

Comment: Erm, don't press the Enter key then.  And don't swallow exceptions.  Debug with Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions.

Comment: Didn't even think of that :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience, the use of FileWatcher to monitor files as they are dumped and (possibly) move them is more trouble than one would want to manage. Simple reason being that if files are dumped into the directory when your application is down, the FileWatcher wont catch them. I prefer using a Timer that polls at intervals, checking if there are files in the directory and moving them. Using this approach, if new files are dumped in the folder when the application is down (say for maintenance), they will be moved as soon as the app is restarted and the timer starts polling

Answer (score 0):

Not copyiing two files: while you are copying one file, another file is created but raising eventgs is disabled so you are not notified of the event.

Try scanning the directory in `File_OnChanged`, then you will catch this.

Why does it exit? I assume it raises an exception, probably the writign process has not finished writing and you are already accessing that file - which may be not allowed.